# How to reload google guava cache

Tags: java, caching, guava, dropwizard

I am working on dropwizard-java project,I have code till google guava cache functionality.Once the value is written into file,I need to update cache.When I open a certain path,it should update cache in server without restarting.If anyone knows,please help me to write code for reload cache.

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to do this but if you are synchronously writing a file and then want to update your Guava Cache to load that file then you can use [direct insertion](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#inserted-directly).

For alternative population methods and more details see [CachesExplained · google/guava Wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained).

Comment: Thanks,.can you please provide me some example.I need to update cache before server running.I need to update cache by calling it in another method.

Comment: Please read [CachesExplained · google/guava Wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) (specifically the section on [Population](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#population)). You will find various examples. If you want direct insertion then you'll simply do `cache.put(path, file)` (or whatever your keys and values are).